# 2 arrays no foreach

Tags: php

existe como colocar 2 arrays em um mesmo foreach?

Deixa eu explicar o que eu preciso, estou usando a class WideImage para redimensionar as imagens, preciso pegar a extensão da imagem para salva-la posteriormente.
Meu problema esta ai, como eu posso fazer para pegar a extensao de cada imagem do array?

Eu até consigo fazer com um foreach tipo esse:

```
foreach ($image as $imagem) {
    foreach ($imagemExtensao as $extensao) {
        $extensaoDaImagem = pathinfo($extensao, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
        $imagemFinal = $imagem->resize(400, 300);
        $geraNome = md5(time().rand());
        $imagemFinal->saveToFile('imagens/usuarios/' . $geraNome .'.'.$extensaoDaImagem);
        $nomeCompleto = $geraNome.'.'.$extensaoDaImagem;
    }
}
```

Só que ai ele duplica as imagens, os nomes, tudo. Por isso eu preciso fazer uma vez só, ou se tiverem outra ideia.

Comment: Forneça um exemplo da estrutura das `array`s retornada pela classe, para assim entendermos se é bidimensional ou duas isoladas, se é do tipo `assoc` ou `index`. Detalhes como este farão você obter respostas mais rápidas :)

Comment: Uso a função do WideImage para trazer o array de imagens segue função, $image = WideImage::loadFromUpload('imagem', 'imagem.php'); Ai eu preciso usar outra variável para trazer o array com os nomes, para posteriormente pegar a extensão das imagens, $imagemExtensao = $_FILES['imagem']['name']; Por isso preciso do foreach, para conseguir varrer os 2 arrays no mesmo instante.

Comment: Não use os comentários, edite a questão, formule a pergunta e forneça o formato das `arrays` (você pode capturar tal formato usando `print_r`).

Comment: Então você já tem uma array com as extensões, é isso? E ela tem o mesmo tamanho da array de imagens? Os índices das duas arrays são correspondentes? Por exemplo, a imagem em `$image[5]` é a dona da extensão em `$imagemExtensao[5]`?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se são duas arrays "paralelas", numericamente indexadas, e com indexação correspondente, basta fazer um loop em uma delas, e usar o mesmo índice na outra. Por exemplo:

```
foreach ($image as $indice => $imagem) {
    $extensao = $imagemExtensao[$indice];
    $extensaoDaImagem = pathinfo($extensao, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    $imagemFinal = $imagem->resize(400, 300);
    $geraNome = md5(time().rand());
    $imagemFinal->saveToFile('imagens/usuarios/' . $geraNome .'.'.$extensaoDaImagem);
    $nomeCompleto = $geraNome.'.'.$extensaoDaImagem;
}
```

Comment: Tu é o cara, funcionou certinho, Muitoooo Obrigado!!!

Comment: Mais uma ajuda, como eu posso enviar esses nomes das imagens pro banco? hehe estou começando agora, desculpa a ignorância

Comment: @user13840 Aí já é uma pergunta totalmente nova, você pode postar separado. Na nova pergunta, você precisa situar as pessoas sobre o que você já sabe/tentou, qual é o seu banco e como é sua tabela, se você já sabe conectar ao banco, etc.